# React Cascading Dropdowns (Dynamic)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cascadingdropdown

The scenario is as follows: I want to make a reusable cascading dropdown component, however every video/article that I've seen on the topic just uses hard coded dependent dropdowns such as: Country => State => City.

However, for my situation it will not always be the same dependencies. How can I support custom dependency for cascading dropdowns?

For a hardcoded example I would do something along the lines of having one useEffect for each of the options, and make the dependant options change when the parent changes.

I have an object example to iterate through of one page I am trying to accomplish this for:

```
[
  {
    key: 0,
    name: "State",
    parentQuestion: null,
    inputType: "Dropdown",
  },
  {
    key: 1,
    name: "Sublocation",
    parentQuestion: "State",
    inputType: "Dropdown",
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    name: "Operation",
    parentQuestion: "Sublocation",
    inputType: "Dropdown",
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    name: "Installment Number",
    parentQuestion: "Operation",
    inputType: "Dropdown",
  },
  {
    key: 4,
    name: "Upload Directory",
    parentQuestion: null,
    inputType: "File",
  },
  {
    key: 5,
    name: "Download Directory",
    parentQuestion: null,
    inputType: "Directory",
  },
]
```

Is it possible to accomplish this? Or must I hardcode the logic with different hooks for each page?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the `component` built passing the array data as `props`, then iterating over each key on an element of the array, you have to build the `select`s using `map`. For the option values list you have to prepare another object such that

```
optionList={country:[],state:[],city:[]}
```

You have to maintain an `object` with selected options, and onchange of the `select`s you have to modify the `object` for selected options.

**Edit**
Also onchange of `select`s you have to modify the `optionList` object, reducing the options array, for example

if country is selected 'UK' then on the final `object` selected you add the value `final_object={country:'UK'}` and then in `optionList` you have to reduce the options for corresponding `state` and `city`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However I must ask for clarification.

For a hardcoded example I would do something along the lines of having one useEffect for each of the options, and make the dependant options change when the parent changes.

How would I achieve that part specifically, in a reusable way that doesn't require me to hardcode the logic for each page?

Comment: using `useEffect` in my opinion would be a more complex, as you'll have to maintain state variables for each `select` type, therefore I suggested the `onchange` approach as modifications would be more simpler. I have also edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you, 

It is still a little fuzzy to me, but I will work on implementing what you described and I will come back to post the final code

Comment: Sure. I understood your approach of using `useEffect` but in my opinion defining/using variables/object and then using them for the `dependency` mapping of `useEffect` would become more complex, rather maintaining a single `final_selected_object` would be simpler.